# How to use Hiptest publisher executing test scripts using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium

I have written scenario using gherkins keyword and exported the script using Java/TestNg framework, now I have zip file containing actionword, project test and yml config file. Now I want to run my script through selenium web driver but I am not able to do so as I have done whatever mentioned in   https://github.com/hiptest/hiptest-publisher#hiptest-publisher and some post but I'm stuck. Can anybody please help me how to run scenario using selenium webdriver by Step By Step, it would be grateful as I am just a beginner in both selenium and hiptest and my project looking into Hiptest for automation.

Comment: did u try to export from automation section of hiptest?

Comment: Yes i have exported the file .

Comment: Did you follow the tutorial: https://blog.hiptest.net/2015/10/30/tutorial-a-simple-selenium-test-from-hiptest/? It uses hiptest and webdriver and explains the process step by step.